# Нарисовать линию на изображении и перемещать ее

Tags: c#, winapi, api, controls, .net

Я хочу нарисовать линию или группу линий программно на изображении, а затем манипулировать ими (перемещать, изменять размер, вращать). Линии приходят из функции, а затем изображение сохраняется с позициями этих линий.

Есть ли какие-либо корпоративные / открытые программные API для этого?

Comment: А Вы уже изучили, какие методы предоставляет Graphics?

Comment: Как вариант использовать средства WPF. На картинку можете добавлять разные фигуры, а затем по клику находить их в визуальном дереве и манипулировать ими

Answer (score 0):

Для создания графического приложения, как правило, используют WPF или Windows Forms. В обоих можно рисовать линии программно через XML или C#. Советую сразу обратится к учебному сайту metanit. Здесь можно найти информацию о том как использовать WPF или Forms.Там же описано как с помощью C# нарисовать фигуры, прилагаю ссылку:
 [WPF metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/17.3.php)